# Chordal completion of a graph in Python

Tags: python, r, algorithm, igraph, graph-theory

Is there any python library that can find chordal completion of a given graph (aka minimum fill-in problem)? I know that in R package *igraph* there is a function to do it (*is_chordal(G, newgraph = TRUE)*) , but I could not find it in Python version of the library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The chordal completions computed by `is_chordal` aren't guaranteed to be minimum chordal completions, or even minimal.

Comment: Actually, I need any chordal completion, even if it is not minimal it is ok for me

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX in for python has the function you are asking for. See the documentation here:

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/chordal.html

The functions you probably want are:

```
is_chordal(G)                 Checks whether G is a chordal graph.
chordal_graph_treewidth(G)    Returns the treewidth of the chordal graph G.
complete_to_chordal_graph(G)  Return a copy of G completed to a chordal graph
```